# Matplotlib set coordinate

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to set the coordinate from 1 to N, not 0 to N.

I had try to use `set_ylim()` or `set_ybound`, but failed.

```
# Plot the pic.
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.set_title("Distribution of sequence order correlation values")
ax.axes.set_xlabel("Column index")
ax.axes.set_ylabel("Row index")
cax = ax.imshow(tar_data, interpolation='nearest')
cbar = fig.colorbar(cax)
```

[image]

Comment: have you tried `plt.gca().invert_yaxis()` ?

Comment: or maybe since this is `imshow`, try `origin='lower'` or `origin='upper'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution. It comes in two folds.

First, you can use the `extent` keyword of the `imshow` function to specify the extent of your axes. If you want the center of the first pixel to be at position 1, that means the beginning of the pixel is at position 0.5. Similarly, if the center of your last pixel is at position 8, the end of your pixel is at 8.5. This is why you see in my code that the range goes from 0.5 to `nx+0.5`, where `nx` is the number of points in the x direction.

After doing this, your axes will range from 0.5 to 8.5. So, will your ticks. That's not very pretty. To change that, you can redefine your ticks to be going from 1 to 8, using `ax.set_xticks()` and `ax.set_yticks()`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.array([[1,23,12],[24,12,7],[14,9,4] ])
ny, nx = data.shape

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.imshow(data, interpolation='nearest', extent=[0.5, nx+0.5, ny+0.5, 0.5])

xticks = np.arange(nx)+1
yticks = np.arange(ny)+1

ax.set_xticks(xticks)
ax.set_yticks(yticks)

plt.show()
```

[image: Result of this code]